# Convert websites into mobile website format

Tags: php, html, mobile, web

I would like to display other we pages in my mobile webapp, but some web pages will be too cumbersome for use on a tiny mobile device screen. So implement some kind of google mobilizer feature. Is there any API available in PHP so that i can use that to convert these pages into mobile compatible

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got it, we can use skweezer API for this. If you want to see your website in mobile compatible format try this

```
http://www.skweezer.com/s.aspx?q=www.example.com
```

Replace www.example.com with your website URL.

For more details, visit http://company.skweezer.com/

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to do it manually. You should look into responsive CSS layouts. These will adjust the content of the page as the width of the browser changes. So same page will work in a full browser window and mobile.

Look at

- http://www.columnal.com/
- http://lessframework.com/
- http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/

Comment: these things are already using for my webapp, what i need is if i gave an external url to this app, the url content need to be fetched and convert into mobile compatible automatically